# Istio Basic routing rules cant get it working

Tags: istio

I’m trying to set routing rules and I cant get it working.

istioctl version:  1.0.2
kubectl version:  client 1.10.3 / server 1.9.6

I have the following deployments (configurations files below) :
1.  Two simple flask pods 
2.  One NodePort Service
3.  One DestinationRule
4.  One VirtualService

After deploying all the above  I still get reply’s from both two pods instead of only V1 as defined in the VirtualService.
Am I missing anything?

**Pod 1:**

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: flask-v1
spec:
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: flask
  replicas: 1
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: flask
        version: v1
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: flask
        image: simple-flask-example:1.0.0
        imagePullPolicy: IfNotPresent
        ports:
        - containerPort: 5000
```

**Pod 2:**

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: flask-v2
spec:
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: flask
  replicas: 1
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: flask
        version: v2
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: flask
        image: simple-flask-example:2.0.0
        imagePullPolicy: IfNotPresent
        ports:
        - containerPort: 5000
```

**Service nodeport:**

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: flask
  labels:
    app: flask
spec:
  type: NodePort
  ports:
  - port: 80
    name: http
    targetPort: 5000
  selector:
    app: flask
```

**DestinationRule:**

```
apiVersion: networking.istio.io/v1alpha3
kind: DestinationRule
metadata:
  name: flask
spec:
  host: flask
  subsets:
  - name: v1
    labels:
      version: v1
  - name: v2
    labels:
      version: v2
```

**VirtualService:**

```
apiVersion: networking.istio.io/v1alpha3
kind: VirtualService
metadata:
  name: flask
spec:
  hosts:
  - flask
  http:
  - route:
    - destination:
        host: flask
        subset: v1
```

**Requests test:**

```
>>> for x in range(10) : requests.request('GET','http://10.200.167.223').text
...
'{\n    "hello": "world v2"\n}\n'
'{\n    "hello": "world v2"\n}\n'
'{\n    "hello": "world v2"\n}\n'
'{\n    "hello": "world v1"\n}\n'
'{\n    "hello": "world v1"\n}\n'
'{\n    "hello": "world v2"\n}\n'
'{\n    "hello": "world v2"\n}\n'
'{\n    "hello": "world v1"\n}\n'
'{\n    "hello": "world v2"\n}\n'
'{\n    "hello": "world v1"\n}\n'
```

Comment: Did you use sidecar auto-injection or you added sidecar manually? Could you check if sidecars are present in flask pods? It looks like Istio is not involved in the traffic distribution.

Comment: Hey @Ben did you got it working !

Answer (score 3):

Istio routing rules (VirtualService rules) are executed in a client proxy, not in the target service, so if you call the service directly via a NodePort it won't do any of the Istio routing. You need to call it from either another Istio service or through an Istio Gateway.

A simple way to test service routing is using the 
[sleep sample](https://github.com/istio/istio/tree/master/samples/sleep) as a client.

Alternatively you can setup an ingress Gateway for your service like the example described [here](https://istio.io/docs/tasks/traffic-management/ingress/).